# adding directory to PYTHONPATH if it's not already there in fish shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

I want to permanently add a directory path into PYTHONPATH if its not already there, programmatically.
Ideally I'd like to do that without editing ~/.config/fish/config.fish

for PATH, find_add_path -m -v do it (check if path already into userpath, add it if its not there) but I don't know equivalent command for PYTHONPATH.

I'm contemplating using `set` with "universal variable" option but I'd like to check first if the new directory is not already there.

How do I do this check? Is there another way?

[EDIT]
@faho I finally tested through config.fish edition.

```
set -a PYTHONPATH "some path"
if status is-interactive
# Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
end
```

But even after restarting (logout, login), `PYTHONPATH` is not in environment variables and is effectively not *seen* by Python. Yet the variable exists (`echo $PYTHONPAH` displays the value given in config.fish).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Would set -a --export PYTHONPATH "some path" be correct? (It seems to be working)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable does not contain a certain value, use [contains](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/contains.html) like so:

```
if not contains -- /path/to/wherever $PYTHONPATH
    # do something
end

# or, for short
contains -- /path/to/wherever $PYTHONPATH
or # do something
```

To add a value to $PYTHONPATH, use `set` like so

```
set PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH /path/to/wherever
# or with `-a`/`--append`:
set -a PYTHONPATH /path/to/wherever
```

You can combine these two and put them into config.fish:

```
contains -- /path/to/wherever $PYTHONPATH
or set -a PYTHONPATH /path/to/wherever
```

This is the basic idea of what `fish_add_path` does - it just adds a few bells and whistles like `--move`.

> find_add_path -m -v do it (check if path already into userpath, add it if its not there)

It's *fish*_add_path, and the `-m` option, short for `--move`, tells it to *move* the value if it is already included to where it would put it instead.

E.g. if you have a variable of `/bin /my/path`, and you do `fish_add_path --move /my/path`, that will make it `/my/path /bin`. Without `--move` it would just do nothing and leave it at `/bin /my/path`.

---

I would caution against using a universal variable here, because [they interact poorly with exporting](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#why-doesn-t-set-ux-exported-universal-variables-seem-to-work).

I would recommend just putting it into config.fish.

Comment: According to the link you're providing, if I try to use an universal variable for the sake of persistence and if the variable already exists, it will actually not work? Is it correct to say that, except for path with ```fish_add_path``` there is no other way to change an environment variable than editing config.fish?
Universal variable are for creation of variable for all users, not for editing them?

Comment: Universal variables are good if you don't need to export them to other programs. That makes them nice e.g. for colors and fish settings. `fish_add_path` uses $fish_user_paths by default, which is a universal variable that each shell then *adds* to its own global $PATH.

Comment: I'm confused: if I update $PATH with ```fish_add_path``` from a script, I observed that the modification is kept even after closing the terminal, leaving the session,... And the modification is seen by other programs, in other terminals... (which is what I want to achieve with PYTHONPATH)
Yet, you're saying that it modifies a universal variable and that it cannot be exported to another program. What did I misunderstand?

Comment: `fish_add_path` updates a variable called $fish_user_paths. fish then sees that that variable was modified and performs the same changes to $PATH. So $fish_user_paths is universal, and fish adds all paths in $fish_user_paths to $PATH, which isn't universal, and only $PATH is exported. This is a workaround because of the issue with exporting universal variables.

Comment: sorry I cannot test easily now.
do I need double-quote somewhere in case my path is containing white space?
do I need to add --path option?

Comment: Fish does not perform word-splitting like bash, so spaces are irrelevant here and double-quotes around the variable are unnecessary and wrong. Quotes around the literal path (if you did `set PYTHONPATH "/home/me/my path/"`) would be necessary. The `--path` option means that the variable is treated like $PATH and split on `:` - so you can treat it as a list inside fish. Since $PYTHONPATH is named "...PATH" that happens automatically and you don't need to mention it explicitly.